# BarChart Apache POI

Tags: java, excel

I am beginner, I have Sheet, which consists of three parts of data.

[image]

I want to create separated bar charts, for each part.

It would also be useful, if you add a source, from which I could learn more about creating charts in excel using Java.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked into Apache POI [documentation](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/index.html), especially their [examples](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/examples.html)?

Comment: There is no example of a bar chart, if you can mention any example or tutorial, it would be very helpful for me, @JakubCh.

Comment: There is example of [scatter chart](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/examples/ScatterChart.java) and [line chart](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/examples/LineChart.java). I can see that the only difference between them is the [chart type](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/chart/ChartTypes.html) so you could probably reuse the code with `ChartTypes.BAR`.